# "Nested" Named Credential Callout

Tags: security, authentication, customsetting, custom-metadata, namedcredentials

I have a named credential, let's call it NC1, setup for a custom AWS endpoint. This works great using the endpoint and an access key. However, as part of the body of NC1, I need to send an auth username and password for a subsequent system. I wanted to store that subsequent auth info in another name credential, NC2.

My initial thought was to use merge fields to put the username and password in the body of the callout. But when trying this, the merge fields set the body params to NC1s values, not NC2 as desired. My issue is how Named Credentials execute during runtime. When the merge fields are finally "set", it is at the time of call out. So I can't reference NC2's merge values when the actually callout being performed is on NC1's endpoint. It just uses NC1's merge values in the body.

I likely can't use two named credentials in this way. If that is the case, what would be a better option to store one of these endpoint's auth info? This will be part of a managed package and users should have the ability to modify (which is why named credentials would have been perfect and I am hesitant to use protected custom settings or custom metadata). Salesforce review team is going to want these stored securely.

Comment: Better is subjective...but you've answered your own question. You can't use a merge field, thus pick an option from [Storing Sensitive Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm). The doc even talks about your use case.